# ksoap2-android nillable="true" как передать

Tags: android, soap, wsdl, веб-служба

На вебсервисе есть следующий метод:

```
<xs:element name="ModifyInformationRegister">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="DimensionsSelect" type="xs1:ParameterList"/>
<xs:element name="DimensionsResources" type="xs1:ParameterList" nillable="true"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Как мне объяснил 1сник nill означает, то что я могу не передавать параметр. На php примере, он также не передается. Если я попытаюсь не вставить этот параметр в запрос то получаю следующий ответ:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Неизвестная ошибка. Недостаточно параметров операции
по причине:
Недостаточно параметров операции' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@2c72282a
```

Использую ksoap2-android 3.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался оказывается надо было создать пустой объект(комплексный тип в понятиях 1с) ему добавить аттрибут с верным типом и именем. И этому аттрибуты явным образом прописайть namespace :http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance. В это отрывке я формирую параметр для запросса который может быть nillable="true"

```
            ParameterList listInsert = new ParameterList(Auth.NAMESPACE_COMPLEX_TYPE,"DimensionsResources");
            AttributeInfo nilAttribut = new AttributeInfo();
            nilAttribut.setName("nil");
            nilAttribut.setValue(true);
            nilAttribut.setNamespace(SoapEnvelope.XSI);
            nilAttribut.setType(PropertyInfo.BOOLEAN_CLASS);
            listInsert.addAttribute(nilAttribut);
            request.addProperty("DimensionsResources",listInsert);
```